# Password Strength

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

If passwords of exactly $8$-characters are used, and the character set consists of just lower-case alpha (a-z), how many passwords are possible?

Expand the character set to include (A-Z), (a-z), ($0$-$9$), and $10$ punctuation characters.
How many $8$-char passwords are possible?

Now with passwords of $7$, $8$, $9$, and $10$ characters are allowed. How many total passwords are possible?

Answer (score 4):

Since repetition of characters is allowed, and order matters, you need only compute $T^n$ where $T$ is the total number of characters available, and $n$ is the length of your password.

For example, when you can use only lower case letters, $T=26$ and $n=8$, so the total number of passwords is $26^8 = 208 827 064 576$.